# Gathering Output of Multiple Tkinter Checkbuttons

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, variables, checkbox, tkinter

I have a dict that contains data like `devices = {'dev1': ['192.168.200.73', 'foo', 'bar'], 'dev2': ['192.168.200.109', 'foo', 'bar']}` I print the dict as checkbuttons and I need to get the selected checkbuttons name. Essential code:

```
for name in devices:
v1 = BooleanVar()
c= Checkbutton(top, text=name, variable= v1)
c.grid(columns=1, rows= rs)
rs +=1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does the dict look like? Also, have you tried making the Checkbuttons in a for loop yourself? What problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: OK, I was working on it and recently found out how easy it is but still I need to get the states of every single checkbutton. Also my dict looks like  `devices = {'d1': ['192.168.2.73', 'p', 'p'], 'd2': ['192.168.2.109', 'p', 'p']}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

devices = {'dev1': ['192.168.2.73', 'foo', 'bar'],
           'dev2': ['192.168.2.109', 'foo', 'bar']}

check_dict = dict() # Dict of checkbox names and IntVars
for name in devices:
    var = IntVar()      # Create an IntVar for the checkbox
    chk = Checkbutton(root, text=name, variable=var, onvalue = 1, 
                      offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
    chk.pack()
    check_dict[name] = var  # Save name and IntVar reference

def go(event):  # Prints out all checkbox IntVars on <space>
    for name, var in check_dict.items():
        print(name, var.get())

root.bind('<space>', go)
root.mainloop()
```

Example which uses a list instead, and grid:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

devices = {'dev1': ['192.168.2.73', 'foo', 'bar'],
           'dev2': ['192.168.2.109', 'foo', 'bar']}

check_list = [] # List of chexkbox names and IntVars
for name in devices:
    var = IntVar()          # Create an IntVar for the checkbox
    chk = Checkbutton(root, text=name, variable=var, onvalue = 1, 
                      offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
    chk.grid()
    check_list.append([name,var])  # Save name and IntVar reference

def go(event):  # Prints out all checkbox IntVars on <space>
    for v in check_list:
        print(v[0], v[1].get())

root.bind('<space>', go)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get the part that you print the vars I don't see them, what is  <space>?. Also how do I append them to a list?

Comment: And where do you specify the position of buttons, I think it goes with appending kinda stuff but since window space is limited I need to change positions. I know how to do it but where is the chk.grid() thing?

Comment: I bound the SPACEBAR to the function `go()` so that it will print all names and IntVars when you press the spacebar. As for positions, you can put them anywhere you like. I used `pack()` in my example but you can use `grid()`, they are both geometry managers. I'll add an example which uses list instead of dict.

Comment: So firstly, how can I use a button as SPACEBAR? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The list contains sub-lists, each with the name of the device and then a reference to the IntVar associated with that checkbox. When I say spacebar I mean the actual physical spacebar on your keyboard. Press the spacebar on the keyboard and the function `go()` will run and print the contents of the list.